# MySQL Database Table optimization for FASTER Querying & Performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance, primary-key, database-indexes

I have 2 tables in a my MySQL Database.
Let's call 1st `main`, 2nd `final`.

```
TABLE `main` has the structure         |    TABLE `final` has the structure
                                       |
`id` --> PRIMARY KEY (Auto Increment)  |    `id` --> PRIMARY KEY (Auto Increment)
                                       |    `id_main` -->  ?? (Need help here)
                                       |
id | name    | info                    |     id | id_main | name    | info(changed)
---------------------                  |     ---------------------------------------
1  | Peter   | 5,9                     |     1 |    2     | Butters  | 0.3,34
2  | Butters | 3,3                     |     2 |    4     | Stewie   | 1.2,4.4
3  | Stan    | 2,96                    |     3 |    1     | Peter    | 5.7,0.9
4  | Stewie  | 1,84                    |     4 |    3     | Stan     | 4.8,0.74
```

After analysing data in `main` the results get put into `final`.
As you can see `final` has an extra column (`id_main`) which points back to `main`.`id`

In actuality these 2 tables are 100 million+ rows each, my problem arises while performing SQL queries.

How should `final` especially (`id` & `id_main`) be configured so that Querying from `main` to `final` is the fastest.

Can I do away with `final.id` (PRIMARY KEY, Auto Increment) & keep 
`final.id_main` (As an UNIQUE Index?)

OR

Should I keep `id` AS PRIMARY KEY (AI) & `final.id_main` AS UNIQUE Index?

I would be making calls like:

```
int id_From_Main= 10000;
SELECT `id_main` FROM `final` WHERE `id`='"+id_From_Main+"'
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the query `SELECT id_main FROM final WHERE id='"+id_From_Main+"'`? You're trying to select the value of ID from main by ID from main.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` you need help with.

Comment: Or is your question about how to efficiently `INSERT` 100M rows into `final`?  Or do you use `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a 1:1 relation between those tables, I don't see any reason why they would need two separate auto-incremented primary keys.

I would remove the `final.id` column and have the `final.id_main` as a non-auto-incremented primary key and a foreign key to the `main.id` column.

In general, you can also have a table without a primary key at all. It depends on if you want to be able to select specific individual rows or not.

I don't understand your query `SELECT id_main FROM final WHERE id = '"+id_From_Main+"'` — you're trying to select the value of ID from main by ID from main. What's the purpose, why are you trying to get the value you already have?

Anyway, you're not providing enough information to give you a qualified answer. You have to optimize you data structures according to queries you'll be doing.

Make sure you have indexes on columns which you are using in the `WHERE` clausule. If you're selecting by `final.id_main`, have an index on that column. If you're selecting by `final.id_main` and `final.name`, have a composite index on both columns, etc.

Do you really need to have the `name` column in both tables? It's a bad database design, unless it's some performance optimization (to avoid a join).

So, you should:

1. collect all queries you're currently using, set proper indexes according to them
2. remove any unnecessary columns (e.g. `final.id`, `final.name`)
3. use the [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) on your queries to get execution information (you can also use the [Explain analyzer](https://mariadb.org/explain_analyzer/analyze/) to help you interpret the results)
4. you can try [query profiling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html)

Comment: I completely agree with you on `final.id_main as a non-auto-incremented primary key` but not on the `foreign key to the main.id column` part, I don't see any performance benefits in doing this, aren't foreign key's primary purpose just to help DB administrators manoeuvre between tables? 
Haha sorry about that I should have elaborated on it   `int id_From_Main= 10000;
SELECT id_main FROM final WHERE id='"+id_From_Main+"'` is java code.

Comment: @InternetOfThings - `FOREIGN KEYs` do three things: (1) integrity checks (not at issue in this Q&A), and (2) provide an `INDEX` if there is not one already, and (3) tell _humans_ how the tables are related.  Since a `PRIMARY KEY` _is a_ `UNIQUE INDEX`, you would already satisfy (2).  (1) and (3) are not critical.

Comment: @InternetOfThings Doesn't matter what language it is, it doesn't make a sense logically. You're trying to select value of `final.id_main` where `final.id == id_main`. Simply remove `final.id`, which seems to be useless in your case.

Answer (score -1):

In mysql, you have to define id as PK because it is auto_increment. Define id_main as UNIQUE.

Comment: The primary key doesn't have to be auto-incremented and you don't need an auto increment column in a table at all.

Comment: in mysql, if a column is auto-increment, it has to be in the PK. But whether the auto-increment column id is required is out of the scope of the discussion.

Comment: No, that's exactly what's OP asking for — if he should keep the `final.id` auto increment primary key or remove it.